# How to install programmatically Windows 10 Text To Speech Voices on Windows 10 computer user?

Tags: windows-10, inno-setup, text-to-speech

I need to do an installer that adds new Language Voices onto a Windows 10 computer user.

I read some post that mentioned this manual procedure but that doesn't help on my request because it requires that user will install the language:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-voices-for-immersive-reader-read-mode-and-read-aloud-4c83a8d8-7486-42f7-8e46-2b0fdf753130

What I would like to do is to Run the installation of the language.

Here, I see that for old Windows version (but not for Windows 10!) is possible to download and install the **Runtime** and the **Package language**:

**Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime Languages (Version 11)**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224

I tried to install the runtime and to install the French package **MSSpeech_SR_fr-FR_TELE.msi** and **MSSpeech_TTS_fr-FR_Hortense.msi** but it doesn't work.

I think that those installers are not designed for Windows 10 because nothing will appear in Windows 10 Language Settings and onto the registry:

***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens***

***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\SPEECH\Voices\Tokens***

Just to try, I've manually added Chinese and English language as additional languages (following the first link that I paste here) and that language will appear as I expected onto the Windows Registry Keys that I mentioned (and on the system).

So, someone has an idea what my Inno Setup Installer should do to add new languages on Windows 10?

Thanks
Cheers

Comment: Maybe you should first ask a generic question about installing a new voice from command-line - on [su] or [sf]. It will then be probably easy to implement that in Inno Setup. And if not, you will have a way more specific question to ask here.

Comment: ok thank you, I've posted this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1396570/how-to-add-install-a-new-tts-language-voice-onto-windows-10-by-cmd-line

Comment: ok I've done as described here: [https://superuser.com/questions/1397131/windows-powershell-how-to-set-and-run-download-of-tts-language-onto-windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/1397131/windows-powershell-how-to-set-and-run-download-of-tts-language-onto-windows-10)

Comment: So were you able to implement this in Inno Setup?

Comment: In Inno, I've done it on this way: `Exec(ExpandConstant('powershell.exe'), '-command "& {$OldList = Get-WinUserLanguageList; $OldList = $OldList + ''' + LangCulture + '''; &''Set-WinUserLanguageList'' -Force -LanguageList $OldList; exit}"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);`

Comment: That is the translation of this command: `powershell -command "& {$OldList = Get-WinUserLanguageList; $OldList = $OldList + 'es-ES'; &'Set-WinUserLanguageList' -Force -LanguageList $OldList; exit}"`

Comment: In my script `LangCulture` with a simple loop is updated with more culture languages: `CommandLangs:= CommandLangs + '; $OldList = $OldList + ''' + LangCulture + ''''`

Comment: But I see that this `Powershell` command is a definitive way to install languages because sometimes I see that language will be added on the Windows list but the Download inside Windows properties ([see this picture](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/a25d7260-d9ba-45a0-8bf8-1a50d65579b8.jpg)) doesn't start for some reason. Has someone some suggestion to force TTS download-install?

Comment: :( first script example it's a for a single command but the the following is for the loop that I mentioned: `Exec(ExpandConstant('powershell.exe'), '-command "& {$OldList = Get-WinUserLanguageList' + CommandLangs + '; &''Set-WinUserLanguageList'' -Force -LanguageList $OldList; exit}"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);`